# Insert number value to terms with ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have issue with inserting terms while typing select input field. Strings will be correctly inserted but if there is date or number values for terms then it inserts term ID.

I have a lot term fields and some of them are numeric fields like date, mileage, etc..

My Code:

```
function jl_insert_term_if_not_exists($term, $taxonomy) {
    if (empty($term) || is_numeric($term)) { //tried is_string() then every value inserted as term ID
        return $term;
    }

    if ($result = term_exists($term, $taxonomy)) {
        return $result['term_id'];
    }

    $result = wp_insert_term($term, $taxonomy);

    if (!is_wp_error($result)) {
        return $result['term_id'];
    }
}

function jl_acf_update_value( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
    if ($field['type'] == 'taxonomy'
        && in_array($field['field_type'], array('select', 'multi_select'))
        && strpos($field['wrapper']['class'], 'acf-select-tags') !== false)
    {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            if ($term_id = jl_insert_term_if_not_exists($value, $field['taxonomy'])) {
                $value = $term_id;
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($value as &$item_value) {
                if ($term_id = jl_insert_term_if_not_exists($item_value, $field['taxonomy'])) {
                    $item_value = $term_id;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $value;
}
add_filter('acf/update_value', 'jl_acf_update_value', 5, 3);
function jl_acf_input_admin_footer() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        acf.add_filter('select2_args', function( args, $select, settings, $field, instance ){
            if ($field.hasClass('acf-select-tags')) {
                console.log($field.hasClass('acf-select-tags'));
                args.tags = true
            }
            
            return args;
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('acf/input/admin_footer', 'jl_acf_input_admin_footer');
```